# Error when trying to apply box-cox transformation to a column in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, scipy, scipy.stats

This should be very basic, but there seem to be no post about it here (well, I didn't find any).

I tried to apply box-cox transformation to a column in Pandas, but got this error:

```
ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index
```

This is what I've done:

```
from scipy import stats 
df['boxcox_col_1'] = stats.boxcox(df['col_1'])
```

Shouldn't this work?

It's just a regular pandas column with numeric variables ranging from 0.005 to 39 and no missing values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
a, b = stats.boxcox(df['col_1'])
df['boxcox_col_1'] = a
```

Read the documentation here: [BoxCox](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.boxcox.html)

Answer (score 2):

The code be should as :

```
df['boxcox_col_1'] = stats.boxcox(df['col_1'])[0]
```

as it returns , one argument more .That results in your error. [Refer](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.boxcox.html)